# How to set and get values from cookie in EmberJS using ember-simple-auth

Tags: ajax, authentication, cookies, token, ember-simple-auth

Excuse my naivety, but I am new to sessions, cookie based authentication and Python Tornado. I am trying to access an API written in python Tornado, and am using Ember CLI for the client. I can't seem to set cookie values in the request sent to the server. How does one set the cookie correctly in AJAX/Ember.JS?

**Techs I'm using:**

- Ember CLI
- Ember Simple Auth
- Python Tornado

**My situation**

1. **What I have:**  A log in page where users can try to log in.
2. **What I need:**  A way to set parts of the successful response from the server into a local storage location, or cookie.
3. **What I have:**  An API endpoint that I am accessing using AJAX
4. **What I need:**  A way to pass parts of the log-in response data as a 'cookie' as the server is throwing an error saying that the cookie is invalid or missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so whomever is running into the same problem, I basically had to set the following ajax setting in my "findAll" function for my model, and on just the authenticate method.

```
...
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
success: succsFunction, 
error: errorFunction...
```